# Wanting to place in imagine inside a DIV using CSS but isn't showing image?

Tags: css, image, html, background-image

I am creating a php that will be included in the rest of my pages, I want it to hold the logo, slogan and link to the CSS styling for all the pages for the site. 
I am doing this using:

```
<?php 
require_once("home_start.php");
    ?>
```

at the beginning of all of my pages.

However, in this page i wanted to create an empty DIV, which using CSS (which i have liked) i will  be able to place the logo (a GIF) inside.

my div looks like this:

```
<div id="title">

</div>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
#title {

  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(graphics/logo.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width:250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Why isn't the imagine appearing? 
(please bear in mind I am quite new to coding and this site)

Comment: Give your div a height.

Comment: also, put quotes around your image url, and probably best to make it absolute so it doesn't break when you change directories. `url('http://domain.com/graphics/logo.gif');` or `url('/graphics/logo.gif');`

Comment: And as the other say, a height and quotes around the url('path/file;)
If you want to leave a div empty but visible, put &nbsp; in it. Spaces alone won't do the trick usually.

Comment: Also, standard practice on a website is to put the logo in as a real image (not a background image) and to put a link to the home page around this image so if this logo is clicked on from anywhere within the site it will take the user back to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend that your logo goes in an anchor/link tag e.g. `<a href="/">[LOGO HERE]</a>` instead of using a `<div>` with a background image. This helps navigation and has SEO benefits. You would end up with something like this:

```
<div id="title"><a title="Your company name" href="/"><img src="graphics/logo.gif"/></a></div>
```